# Condition erros in vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to check my variable is empty. I think my code looks fine.
But it is not working..

Current my vue.js version is `2.5.13`

Below is my code

```
<template>
    <div v-if="Object.keys(this.myValues).length === 0">
        is empty
    </div>
    <div v-else>
        good
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data: function() {
    return {
      myValues: new Object()
    };
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: Try omitting the `this` from `Object.keys(this.myValues)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the working example `data` refers to current template so remove `this`

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#el',
  data: function() {
    return {
      myValues: new Object(),
      another: {some:'value'}
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.13/vue.js"></script>
<div id="el">
    <div v-if="Object.keys(myValues).length === 0">
        myValues is empty
    </div>
    <div v-else>
        myValues have some element
    </div>
    
    <div v-if="Object.keys(another).length === 0">
        Another is empty
    </div>
    <div v-else>
        Anoter have some element
    </div>
</div>
```